# Error using inline preview in texstudio

Tags: texstudio, inline

I use texstudio as my editor and on one of my computers (the other one works fine) I get the following error message when doing inline preview (by highlighting text, right clicking and pressing "preview selection/parentheses"):

`Process started: latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode "PdG940".tex'
 Process exited with error(s)
 Process started: dvipng.exe -T tight -D 120 "PdG940".dvi
 Process exited with error(s)`

The text gets highlighted but no preview appears

I need help getting my inline preview working again (it hasn't been working for months now). Thanks for any help.

This link leads to what I think is the same question as mine (he didn't get any answers) http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/638/

Answer (score 1):

Go to Options -> Configure Texstudio -> Preview. Choose in Command, "Preview with pdflatex"

The reason could be that I use the packages epstopdf or that in the package graphicx I include the option pdftex, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem after a texlive medium installation and solved it. All I did is to install 'preview' and 'varwidth' package in 'tex live manager'.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!